# Vlookup is not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I use the below code, i am getting error 2042

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim Dat As Variant
For i = 1 To 10
    LV = "10000100"
    Dat = Application.VLookup(LV, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B20"), 2, False)
Next

End Sub
```

Lookup array which i keep it another sheet (Sheet2)

```
10000100    1/2/2017
10000110    1/2/2017
10000220    2/2/2017
10000230    4/2/2017
10000140    3/4/2017
10000350    1/2/2017
10000160    1/2/2017
10000170    5/2/2017
10000180    1/2/2017
10000190    1/2/2017
10000200    1/2/2017
```

Comment: @brettdjs solution works for me; ie replace the LV in the VLookup with CLng(LV).  Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: (1) Determine whether column A contains a number or a text value - format a cell using a "#,###" format - if it shows the commas then it is a number, if it doesn't then it is text.  Let us know the answer.  (2) If it is text, work out the length of the field - insert a formula in C2 which says `=LEN(A2)` - if it says anything other than 8 then there are leading or trailing spaces.  Let us know the answer.

Comment: Using the code you have given I was able to run it without any problems, are you sure the values you are looking for exsist in sheet 2? The only time I get error 2042 is if the value the vlookup is looking for doesnt exsist on sheet 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at a number then your code has a mismatch as you are looking for a string - what happens if you try:

```
Public Sub Test()
Dim Dat As Variant
Dim LV As Long
For i = 1 To 10
LV = 10000100
Dat = Application.VLookup(LV, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B20"), 2, False)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Duraisamy codes seems okay. Check your data columns `Format`

Comment: Does the list on sheet 2 definitely start in row 2, not row 1?

Comment: I believe the value Duraisamy is looking for doesnt exsist in sheet 2, the only time I get error 2042 with the vloopup is when the value doesnt exsist (It returns the date in a number format though)